# Session data is not saved on Codeigniter Rest API

Tags: codeigniter

I create web service use codeigniter, after user login successfully I want session data is saved so this is my code

```
$data_session = array(
   'id' => 1,
   'status' => 'logged',
   'token' => 'NaTVbUokZ2wq6qxb7Cwz5TusncOGHOix_NHDvISjQu9OYIHxIo'
);

$this->session->userdata = $data_session;
```

But when I display session data with `$this->session->all_userdata()` the value is `null`, thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the session data before you can retrieve it's value. Also please make sure that you are loading session library, it might be worthwhile loading it using the 'autoload.php' file inside the config folder.

```
$data_session = array(
   'id' => 1,
   'status' => 'logged',
   'token' => 'NaTVbUokZ2wq6qxb7Cwz5TusncOGHOix_NHDvISjQu9OYIHxIo'
);

$this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
```

Also to retrieve the value trying using something like this

```
$token = $this->session->userdata('token');
```

Comment: The correct answer is in here, though it is buried and without explanation.  [Use `set_userdata()` to set session data](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data), not `userdata`, as OP has.